# Markdown - Links in page

Tags: link, markdown, github

Com markdown o link in page:

```
* [Minha localização](#minha-localização)
```

aponta para

```
## Minha localização
```

No título, markdown insere automaticamente o `id="minha-localização"` (acentuado), mas quando o código é convertido para HTML a acentuação no link é extirpada resultando em:

```
* [Minha localização](#minha-localizacao) (sem acentuação)
```

mas a acentuação no título não é extirpada resultando em quebra do link.

Você conhece a solução? Se sim, por favor indique.

Comment: Convertido aonde, no Github, ou algum software? Dê detalhes, existem muitos "compiladores" de Markdown, pode ser um bug pode ser falta de atualização do software, pode ser qualquer coisa, só você dando os detalhes necessários poderemos deduzir algo.

Comment: @Guiherme Nascimento - Sim a conversão é no GitHub

Comment: Poderia fornecer um exemplo de uma página sua do github que isto ocorreu?

Comment: Renderização: https://maujor.github.io/railsgirlsguides/install

----------------

Markdow: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Maujor/railsgirlsguides/master/_posts/2013-05-02-install.markdown

Comment: Pronto Mauricio, aproveitei e editei sua pergunta

Comment: Estou fazendo alguns testes no meu github, se conseguir descobrir lhe informo.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento e a quem interessar possa: "Salvei" o arquivo markdown com codificação de caracteres uff-8 e resolveu. Veja o resultado em: https://railsgirlsmaceio.github.io/install

Comment: Imaginei que fosse isto, provavelmente é um BUG ou limitação mesmo do github-pages. +1 pra pergunta e pro comentário.